# Joomla My Sql Query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have 2 tables in Joomla:

- `Entitlements`:`(User_id, entitlement_amount, reference_year)`
- `Charges`:`(User_id, charge_amount, reference_year)`

Both must be linked to the users core table using the `User_id` as a foreign key.

`Entitlements` has entries with users not necessarily included in `Charges`. `Charges` table has entries not necessarily included in the `Entitlements`.

I need to link all 3 tables in such a way so that in each row, I will have the `User_id(name)`, the `SUM(entitlement_amount)` and the `SUM(charge_amount)`.

The results must be grouped by `employee`, `reference_year`. 
If no `SUM` is calculated then to display `0`.

Here is my code below.

```
    $query->select( $this->getState(
    'list.select',
    'a.id,' .                                
    'a.employee_id,' .      
    'ac.employee_id,' .     
    'a.reference_year,' .      
    'ac.reference_year,' .  
    'u.name,' .
    'SUM(a.entitlement), ' .                                
    'SUM(ac.charge)'));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__employee_entitlement').' AS a');

    $query->join('LEFT OUTER', $db->quoteName('#__users', 'u') . ' ON (' .         
    $db->quoteName('a.employee_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('u.id') .')');

    $query->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__absence_charge', 'ac') . ' ON (' 
    . $db->quoteName('ac.employee_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('u.id') . 
    ')');

    $query->group($db->quoteName('a.employee_id')) ;      
    $query->group($db->quoteName('a.reference_year')) ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want us to deliver the solution or what? Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: I have tried the code shown above, which apparently delivers false results.  Could you comment on the joins of the tables? Is there any correction to be made?

Comment: Have you noticed something?

Comment: I do not see anything strikingly obvious. Do you have access to PHPMyAdmin so that you could test the SQL directly?

Comment: I  have access to PHPMyAdmin. My SQL is wrong, this is for sure. Either the joining of the tables or the groupings. Running it gives me wrong results.

Comment: Actually, thinking again: what if you make the first join a RIGHT join? If that does not help, can you possibly explain/illustrate the meaning of "wrong"?

Comment: I tried but with no success. I can say that the result is not correct because when i see the actual records in the table without the grouping and the SUM I don't get what is expected. Perhaps what I am asking is not feasible?

Comment: It is certainly feasible, but I'm afraid can not help further, sorry...

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Why are you doing `$this->getState`? You don't want the states in your `SELECT` do you? you want the field names.   Please add `echo $query->dump()` after the last line of the code block above and test the generated query in PHPMyAdmin.  Also